# ValueError while using fittedvalues function in python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels, varmax

I'm trying to fit a multivariate timeseries data which has been predicted using the VARMAX model but when I try to convert the data to panda series it gives me the following error.

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

The program is:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax import VARMAX
model = VARMAX(indexedDataset_logscale, order=(1, 1))
results_VARMAX = model.fit(disp=False)

predictions_VARMAX_diff = pd.Series(results_VARMAX.fittedvalues, copy=True)
print(predictions_VARMAX_diff.head(10))
```

How am I supposed to handle this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the value of `indexedDataset_logscale`?

Comment: If it's multivariate, then it has several columns, pd.Series is only for 1-dim arrays.

Comment: @arnab, `indexedDataset_logscale` contains 6 columns including the index column in which the index column is the timestamps.